Unable to read docker env variable in java app
In my java app, I read a env variable as:
String inputPath = System.getProperty("INPUT_PATH");

I then run this in a docker container as:
docker run -it -e INPUT_PATH='/home/...data/input.txt' myapp:1.0.0

But program is unable to read the env var INPUT_PATH.
What mistake am I am making here?

since you are passing environment variable you need to read environment variable as well: use System.getenv() instead of System.getProperty()

Use System.getenv(String name) to access environment variables.
String inputPath = System.getenv("INPUT_PATH");

Reference - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-
